# Override iOS iframe automatically setting height with JS

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe

I am currently using iframes to embed my page as a widget into other web pages. It works perfectly in all browsers besides mobile Safari due to iOS iframe height adjusting automatically to the height of its content. This behavior breaks the infinite scroll I've set up in the app.

Essentially, here is my HTML:

```
<div class='feed'>
   <iframe scroll='auto' width='100%' height='700' src='link'>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.feed {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I've read that using `scroll='no'` on the iframe would disable the height, however it also disables the scrolling for all browsers.

**I need to ideally force the iframe to a specific height (`ie. 700px`) while allowing the scrolling to happen within the iframe.**

I've tried using JS to force the height on iframe load as well, to no avail.